# How to transfer a Firebase RTDB snapshot.value into a Dart/Flutter Class instance

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I am trying to transfer a data snapshot of a Firebase RTDB node into a suitable data structure in Flutter. The node contains a list of keys (userids) each of which contains a list of keys (userids). Each child contains a key/value pair. I want to transfer this data into a list of objects of type AccessList. I need advice on what my AccessList class definition(s) should look like and how to move the data into an instance of them - because the key values are variable I cannot simply refer to them as in a map.

Really can't get my head around this. :-(

Here is a screen dump of the database node:

[image]

Here is the snapshot.value I retrieve:

```
snapshot.value: {iSAwyU7bwKO8OBvFDr1DKYZjc5q1: {0cSLt3Sa0FS26QIvOLbin6MFsL43: {accessType: GivenTo}}, xuxkuOjwhOaKVWXtTaK2bP4chdF2: {kblbVzEtkRZ9QREJdSKOqxVJCYg1: {accessType: GivenBy}}, ayEcqzihYEOfTakY5FVaxSgLsjv2: {0cSLt3Sa0FS26QIvOLbin6MFsL43: {accessType: GivenBy}}, as22efYvdjhLeN6U8JF5ozEoQks2: {0cSLt3Sa0FS26QIvOLbin6MFsL43: {accessType: GivenBy}}, 0cSLt3Sa0FS26QIvOLbin6MFsL43: {iSAwyU7bwKO8OBvFDr1DKYZjc5q1: {accessType: GivenBy}, ayEcqzihYEOfTakY5FVaxSgLsjv2: {accessType: GivenTo}, as22efYvdjhLeN6U8JF5ozEoQks2: {accessType: GivenTo}}, kblbVzEtkRZ9QREJdSKOqxVJCYg1: {xuxkuOjwhOaKVWXtTaK2bP4chdF2: {accessType: GivenTo}}}
```

Here is the structure of the Dart code which defines two classes, one included in the other:

```js
class AccessList {
  final String authUserId;
  final List<AccessListItem> accessListItems;

  AccessList({
    @required this.authUserId,
    this.accessListItems,
  });
}

class AccessListItem {
  final String sailorId; // Access relates to this sailor id
  final String accessType;

  AccessListItem({
    @required this.sailorId,
    @required this.accessType,
  });
}
```

A simplified version of the code I have tried so far is:

```js
await _referenceSailorBoardAccess.once().then(
  (DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    final List<AccessList> _testFetchedAccessList = [];
    final Map<String, dynamic> _testAccessListData =
        Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);
        
    if (snapshot.value != null) {
      _testAccessListData.forEach((String authId, dynamic accessData) {
        final AccessList accessList = AccessList(
          authUserId: authId,
          accessListItems: accessData.toList,
        );
        _testFetchedAccessList.add(accessList);
      });
    }
```

It obviously doesn't work as I haven't a clue how to process the accessListItems list. I get the following error:

> NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance getter 'toList'.
>   I/flutter (16564): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:1
>   I/flutter (16564): Tried calling: toList

Really hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Have you gotten an answer to this yet?

Comment: Nope, I gave up.